# PHP: RegEx fails to match on HTML page retrieved using file_get_contents

Tags: php, regex

```
        $url = "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/7656119XXXXXXXXX/";
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
        $regExd = '/<div class=\"profile_in_game_joingame\">\n\s+.?<a href=\"(steam.+?)\"[\s]class=\".+\"/i';
        $a = preg_match($regExd, $content, $matches);

        var_dump($a);
```

I am trying to retrieve a html from page using get_file_contents and then find specific URL from page using RegEx that I built here: https://regex101.com

I tried copying whole HTML source code from file_get_contents return and paste it into tester on that website and it worked perfectly but using my code - it fails to find any matches even though URL searched for is 100% on page.

HTML contents of return from get_file_contents:

```
<div class="profile_in_game_joingame">
                                    <a href="steam://" class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_small_thin">
                        <span>Join Game</span>
                    </a>
                                            </div>
            </div>
                                    </div>
```

That's how it comes back, messed up with white spaces etc.. but if I test my regex rule on tester - it still works fine.

I know the URL is empty but that doesn't matter, its supposed to return steam:// in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay nevermind, apparently I am an idiot, I went over documentation for regex and found issue.

I am not supposed to store preg_match in a variable, it generates array instead $matches.